# Im getting error on xampp localhost

Tags: php

when i try to load php script on xampp localhost i got this error , but this script works prefect on online hosting ..

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(header.php): failed to open stream: No such file
or directory

Filename: core/Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 1

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'header.php'
(include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
C:\xampp\htdocs\doitforfun\system\core\Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code
on line 1
```

here is .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

xampp address is `C:\xampp\htdocs\movie`

Comment: surround your php file in the require_once with quotes so it knows to search for the string and not a variable: `require_once('header.php');`
If your header.php file is in a directory higher than where it's being called from, use this: `require_once('../header.php');`

Comment: how to use plz kindly explain in detail